# SAPUI5: Wizard / Branching - Wait for OData return on complete Event of WizardStep

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

my problem is as follows.

I have a Wizard in Branching mode. On completing a Step of the Wizard, the complete method is called. Within this method I send out an OData call to the Backend to determin the NextStep that should be shown. Hence the call will return the NextStep it is not defined yet and the Framework will Crash with the error, that the NextStep is not defined.

So is there a way to pause/wait/sleep for the return of the OData call without crashing the Framework?

I would appreciate every help.
Thanks!

Example XML:

```
<Wizard id="MainWizard" complete="wizardCompletedHandler" enableBranching="true">
                        <WizardStep id="Step1" title="title" validated="true" subsequentSteps="Step2, Step3" complete="onStepOneComplete"
                            icon="sap-icon://multi-select">
```

Example onStepOneComplete:

```
onStepOneComplete: function(oEvent) {


        this.getView().getModel().submitChanges();

        var iNextStep = parseInt(this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/SomeSet('123')/NextStep"), 10);

        this.byId("Step1").setNextStep(iNextStep);
    }
```

Comment: Please add some code to put some light into what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks, I updated the Post.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "success" callback of `submitChanges`

Something like:

```
onStepOneComplete: function(oEvent) {

    var that = this; // needed to keep "this" object in callback
    this.getView().getModel().submitChanges({
        success: function(oResponse){ 
            var iNextStep = parseInt(
                that.getView().getModel().getProperty("/SomeSet('123')/NextStep"), 10
            );

            that.byId("Step1").setNextStep(iNextStep);
        }
    });

}
```

You can grab the "NextStep" property from the `oResponse` object instead of the model, but I've left your code for clarity on what exactly I'm suggesting.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your Reply. But this does not work because of few reasons.
1. submitChanges does not have a callback unless you use BatchMode.
2. The Framework does rely on the NextStep on click of the button otherwise it will crash, no waiting possible.

To resolve this I will create a Post of how i did it, but in short:
-> Remove Framework "NextStep" Buttons and replace it by my own
-> Function import from backend on click to get the NextStep

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you weren't using batch mode (why not? curious). I see what you mean. Have you tried binding a variable to the `validated` property? This way, you could fire your `onStepOneComplete` once the form (or whatever other conditions must be met) when validation is completed. You can then wait for your async data (NextStep prop)  to come back before setting the step to `validated="true"` and it will already know which next step is there when the user fires the `complete` action.

Comment: Hm I would still need to trigger the submitChanges event before that and therefore a separate button. I cannot afford to do backendcalls on every tiny change.
This would be a great solution otherwise.

Comment: You could use the event on the Form control `onValidateFieldGroup` and use the `Input` (or other controls') `fieldGroupIds` field to control when certain field groups are being "submitted" (pressing enter, cursor leaving the field group) or you can fire the `onValidateFieldGroup` event manually on input change or livechange - whatever you require